# Can a (unity3D)Platform effector work on a circle collider2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity 2D. Can a platform effector work on a circle collider, the reason why I am asking this question is I want a circle collider to let the object coming from outside enter the collider but once it's inside the collider it should not be able to get out of the collider until of course its disable(like fruit in a covered basket)

Have I even tried before asking the question?
In my mind, it was pretty simple until I tried it, probably it's easy but I can't wrap my head around it. I thought of disabling it and enabling it once it enters the collider but that will not work if more than one game object is already in the collider other would fall right. locking the transform will work but just does not seem right. any ideas will help.

before this becomes an article of me rambling about this, I will make it short and ask, if somebody understand this concept how can I achieve this ? just slap to the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Layer-based collision detection.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html

In the beginning you set the object to a layer, which can pass through the barrier and when it enters a collider, you can change the layer of the object to one, which collides with the barrier.